# Ambiguous dependencies only on tests

Tags: java, cdi, quarkus

I'm replacing *Spring-DI* annotations to the *Quarkus-CDI* ones.
While the app is booting fine, and there no functionality loss detected so-far, the tests fail to run due to multiple (mostly repeating) errors such as:

> [..] Ambiguous dependencies for type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper and qualifiers [@Named(value = "objMapper")]
>       - java member: com.proj.repository.MyDao#()
>       - declared on CLASS bean [types=[com.proj.repository.MyElasticRepository, com.proj.repository.DomainDao, java.lang.Object, com.proj.repository.MyDao, com.proj.repository.ElasticRepository], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=com.proj.repository.MyDao]
>       - available beans:
>
> **- PRODUCER METHOD bean [types=[java.io.Serializable, com.fasterxml.jackson.core.ObjectCodec, java.lang.Object, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper, com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Versioned, com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TreeCodec], qualifiers=[@Named(value = "objMapper"), @Default, @Any], target=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper getMapper(), declaringBean=com.proj.config.JacksonConfig]**
>
> **- PRODUCER METHOD bean [types=[java.io.Serializable, com.fasterxml.jackson.core.ObjectCodec, java.lang.Object, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper, com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Versioned, com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TreeCodec], qualifiers=[@Named(value = "objMapper"), @Default, @Any], target=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper getMapper(), declaringBean=com.proj.config.JacksonConfig]**

(1) Note the two bold items are *exactly* the same.
(2) There are few other types which yields the same error (with the adjusted types of-course)

Mapper is defined as:

```
public class JacksonConfig implements SerializerAdapter<ObjectMapper> {
    ...

    @Named("objMapper")
    @Produces
    public ObjectMapper getMapper() {
        return ...
    }
}
```

Can you explain why is this occurring? 
How can I fix this so tests will run?
Can you suggest a way to solve such an error where the supposed two erroneous declarations being exactly the same?

Answer (score 1):

Have you done a full clean of your application?

Because it looks a lot like you have 2 version of the classes producing the beans.

Comment: Yes I have. Both _mvn clean install_, and manual remove of target directories.

Comment: Then please work on a reproducer and open a bug, we will have a look. You are sure you don't still have a few Spring annotations that could trigger generating the Spring bean generation?

Comment: No spring annotations left... And the _quarkus-spring-di_dependency is removed from all modules.

Comment: One class in /scr/main/java and one in /src/test/java ?